# Setting properties on message produced for RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

We are using spring cloud stream to consume and produce messages for Rabbitmq.

We have a requirement to read Correlation Id from the incoming message and set it on the produced message.

We are able to read the same using message.getHeaders() but how to set it on the outgoing message?

When using MessageBuilder.setHeader() we are able to send the value but in rabbit management console it appears under headers and not properties.

Both the producer and consumer applications for us are not using spring cloud stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the `AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID` header? That is mapped to/from the property. If you are using anything else, it will be set as a header.

**EDIT**

It works fine for me...

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
    return args -> output.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo",
            Collections.singletonMap(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, "foo")));
}
```

and

[image]

Are you sure you're using the right constant?

Comment: Yes, we are using the `CORRELATION_ID` header and so we are able to read it as a header in the incoming message. The issue is when we set it as a header and we retrieve the message in the Rabbit console, we see it within the headers section of the message and not at the property level. So not sure if the consumer application (which does not use cloud stream and is written in a different language) will get it as a property or as a header?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the header we were using the wrong header name while publishing the message. (We were using correlation_id but the correct one is amqp_correlationId and as pointed better to use the AmqpHeaders constants)